# Extract LAUNCHERS from installer created by Install4J

Tags: install4j

I'm looking for a way to extract the launchers of installers created by install4j (mainly Windows installers).
My goal is to send these launchers for inclusion on the white list of antivirus sites.
I tried to use the Executable Processing option, but this operation takes place before the signing of the launchers and the silent mode makes too many changes in the machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to extract files from the executable without running the installer.

At build time, you can pass the

```
--preserve
```

argument to the compiler, or check the "Do no delete temporary directory" check box in the "Build" step of the installer, then the staging directory with the launchers in the %TEMP% directory will not be deleted after the compilation finishes.

Comment: Thanks man, this alternative will help to reach my objective :)